# Set correct size of svg using only the "d=" attribute of path

Tags: reactjs, svg, react-typescript

I'm using an open-source resume tool called [React-Resume-Template](https://github.com/tbakerx/react-resume-template) to build a personal website.

One option is to show social icons like Twitter and LinkedIn. I am adding support for Threads and Substack.

The react component uses svg, and it only allows you to inject the path attribute, which is wrapped by a generic Icon parent container. For example, here's the Twitter icon:

```
const TwitterIcon: FC<IconProps> = memo(props => (
  <Icon {...props}>
    <path
      d="M40.254 127.637c48.305 0 74.719-48.957 74.719-91.403 0-1.39 0-2.777-.075-4.156 5.141-4.547 9.579-10.18 13.102-16.633-4.79 2.602-9.871 4.305-15.078 5.063 5.48-4.02 9.582-10.336 11.539-17.774-5.156 3.743-10.797 6.38-16.68 7.801-8.136-10.586-21.07-13.18-31.547-6.32-10.472 6.86-15.882 21.46-13.199 35.617C41.922 38.539 22.246 26.336 8.915 6.27 1.933 20.94 5.487 39.723 17.022 49.16c-4.148-.172-8.207-1.555-11.832-4.031v.41c0 15.273 8.786 28.438 21.02 31.492a21.596 21.596 0 01-11.863.543c3.437 13.094 13.297 22.07 24.535 22.328-9.305 8.918-20.793 13.75-32.617 13.72-2.094 0-4.188-.15-6.266-.446 12.008 9.433 25.98 14.441 40.254 14.422"
      fill="currentColor"></path>
  </Icon>
));
```

And here is the Icon container component:

```
const Icon: FC<IconProps> = memo(({children, className, svgRef, transform, ...props}) => (
  <svg
    className={className}
    fill="currentColor"
    ref={svgRef}
    transform={transform}
    viewBox="0 0 128 128"
    width="128"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    {...props}>
    {children}
  </svg>
));
```

Here is how my Threads component looks. I used the svg file found [here](https://uxwing.com/threads-icon/) for the path info.

```
const ThreadsIcon: FC<IconProps> = memo(props => (
  <Icon {...props}>
    <path
      d="M105 0h302c57.75 0 105 47.25 105 105v302c0 57.75-47.25 105-105 105H105C47.25 512 0 464.75 0 407V105C0 47.25 47.25 0 105 0z" /><path fill="#fff" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M337.36 243.58c-1.46-.7-2.95-1.38-4.46-2.02-2.62-48.36-29.04-76.05-73.41-76.33-25.6-.17-48.52 10.27-62.8 31.94l24.4 16.74c10.15-15.4 26.08-18.68 37.81-18.68h.4c14.61.09 25.64 4.34 32.77 12.62 5.19 6.04 8.67 14.37 10.39 24.89-12.96-2.2-26.96-2.88-41.94-2.02-42.18 2.43-69.3 27.03-67.48 61.21.92 17.35 9.56 32.26 24.32 42.01 12.48 8.24 28.56 12.27 45.26 11.35 22.07-1.2 39.37-9.62 51.45-25.01 9.17-11.69 14.97-26.84 17.53-45.92 10.51 6.34 18.3 14.69 22.61 24.73 7.31 17.06 7.74 45.1-15.14 67.96-20.04 20.03-44.14 28.69-80.55 28.96-40.4-.3-70.95-13.26-90.81-38.51-18.6-23.64-28.21-57.79-28.57-101.5.36-43.71 9.97-77.86 28.57-101.5 19.86-25.25 50.41-38.21 90.81-38.51 40.68.3 71.76 13.32 92.39 38.69 10.11 12.44 17.73 28.09 22.76 46.33l28.59-7.63c-6.09-22.45-15.67-41.8-28.72-57.85-26.44-32.53-65.1-49.19-114.92-49.54h-.2c-49.72.35-87.96 17.08-113.64 49.73-22.86 29.05-34.65 69.48-35.04 120.16v.24c.39 50.68 12.18 91.11 35.04 120.16 25.68 32.65 63.92 49.39 113.64 49.73h.2c44.2-.31 75.36-11.88 101.03-37.53 33.58-33.55 32.57-75.6 21.5-101.42-7.94-18.51-23.08-33.55-43.79-43.48zm-76.32 71.76c-18.48 1.04-37.69-7.26-38.64-25.03-.7-13.18 9.38-27.89 39.78-29.64 3.48-.2 6.9-.3 10.25-.3 11.04 0 21.37 1.07 30.76 3.13-3.5 43.74-24.04 50.84-42.15 51.84z"
        fill="currentColor"></path>
  </Icon>
));
```

However, when I do this the Threads icon only shows the upper left corner.

[image]

IHere is the generated HTML svg tag:

```
<svg class="h-5 w-5 align-baseline sm:h-6 sm:w-6" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 128 128" width="128" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M105 0h302c57.75 0 105 47.25 105 105v302c0 57.75-47.25 105-105 105H105C47.25 512 0 464.75 0 407V105C0 47.25 47.25 0 105 0z"></path><path fill="currentColor" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M337.36 243.58c-1.46-.7-2.95-1.38-4.46-2.02-2.62-48.36-29.04-76.05-73.41-76.33-25.6-.17-48.52 10.27-62.8 31.94l24.4 16.74c10.15-15.4 26.08-18.68 37.81-18.68h.4c14.61.09 25.64 4.34 32.77 12.62 5.19 6.04 8.67 14.37 10.39 24.89-12.96-2.2-26.96-2.88-41.94-2.02-42.18 2.43-69.3 27.03-67.48 61.21.92 17.35 9.56 32.26 24.32 42.01 12.48 8.24 28.56 12.27 45.26 11.35 22.07-1.2 39.37-9.62 51.45-25.01 9.17-11.69 14.97-26.84 17.53-45.92 10.51 6.34 18.3 14.69 22.61 24.73 7.31 17.06 7.74 45.1-15.14 67.96-20.04 20.03-44.14 28.69-80.55 28.96-40.4-.3-70.95-13.26-90.81-38.51-18.6-23.64-28.21-57.79-28.57-101.5.36-43.71 9.97-77.86 28.57-101.5 19.86-25.25 50.41-38.21 90.81-38.51 40.68.3 71.76 13.32 92.39 38.69 10.11 12.44 17.73 28.09 22.76 46.33l28.59-7.63c-6.09-22.45-15.67-41.8-28.72-57.85-26.44-32.53-65.1-49.19-114.92-49.54h-.2c-49.72.35-87.96 17.08-113.64 49.73-22.86 29.05-34.65 69.48-35.04 120.16v.24c.39 50.68 12.18 91.11 35.04 120.16 25.68 32.65 63.92 49.39 113.64 49.73h.2c44.2-.31 75.36-11.88 101.03-37.53 33.58-33.55 32.57-75.6 21.5-101.42-7.94-18.51-23.08-33.55-43.79-43.48zm-76.32 71.76c-18.48 1.04-37.69-7.26-38.64-25.03-.7-13.18 9.38-27.89 39.78-29.64 3.48-.2 6.9-.3 10.25-.3 11.04 0 21.37 1.07 30.76 3.13-3.5 43.74-24.04 50.84-42.15 51.84z"></path></svg>
```

**Update:** I was able to make it work using a [different svg](https://fontawesomeicons.com/svg/icons/instagram-threads) and adding transform:"scale=(0.66)"

Comment: You will need a different viewBox. Now you have viewBox="0 0 128 128" and your drawing is bigger than this and overflows. Try viewBox="0 0 512 512" Also you have 2 overlapping shapes filled the same color. You won't be able to see them both.

Comment: Frankly, the described icon component is quite inconvenient. You may add additional properties for passing appropriate viewBox values. A fixed viewBox and width height attributes will over complicate icon swapping. If you need to fit a new icon into a 128x128 viewBox: Open you r icon svg in an editor (e.g inkscape) change the document/artboard size to 128x128 and scale the path to get the desired size (and maybe some padding)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to **@enxaneta** for your accurate and valuable comment:

> You will need a different viewBox. Now you have viewBox="0 0 128 128"
> and your drawing is bigger than this and overflows. Try viewBox="0 0
> 512 512" Also you have 2 overlapping shapes filled the same color. You
> won't be able to see them both.

This is what your icon looks like with viewBox="0 0 128 128":

[image]

Set viewBox="0 0 512 512"

```html
<svg class="h-5 w-5 align-baseline sm:h-6 sm:w-6" fill="currentColor"   viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="128" height="128" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<path fill="none" d="M105 0h302c57.75 0 105 47.25 105 105v302c0 57.75-47.25 105-105 105H105C47.25 512 0 464.75 0 407V105C0 47.25 47.25 0 105 0z">
</path>
<path fill="currentColor" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M337.36 243.58c-1.46-.7-2.95-1.38-4.46-2.02-2.62-48.36-29.04-76.05-73.41-76.33-25.6-.17-48.52 10.27-62.8 31.94l24.4 16.74c10.15-15.4 26.08-18.68 37.81-18.68h.4c14.61.09 25.64 4.34 32.77 12.62 5.19 6.04 8.67 14.37 10.39 24.89-12.96-2.2-26.96-2.88-41.94-2.02-42.18 2.43-69.3 27.03-67.48 61.21.92 17.35 9.56 32.26 24.32 42.01 12.48 8.24 28.56 12.27 45.26 11.35 22.07-1.2 39.37-9.62 51.45-25.01 9.17-11.69 14.97-26.84 17.53-45.92 10.51 6.34 18.3 14.69 22.61 24.73 7.31 17.06 7.74 45.1-15.14 67.96-20.04 20.03-44.14 28.69-80.55 28.96-40.4-.3-70.95-13.26-90.81-38.51-18.6-23.64-28.21-57.79-28.57-101.5.36-43.71 9.97-77.86 28.57-101.5 19.86-25.25 50.41-38.21 90.81-38.51 40.68.3 71.76 13.32 92.39 38.69 10.11 12.44 17.73 28.09 22.76 46.33l28.59-7.63c-6.09-22.45-15.67-41.8-28.72-57.85-26.44-32.53-65.1-49.19-114.92-49.54h-.2c-49.72.35-87.96 17.08-113.64 49.73-22.86 29.05-34.65 69.48-35.04 120.16v.24c.39 50.68 12.18 91.11 35.04 120.16 25.68 32.65 63.92 49.39 113.64 49.73h.2c44.2-.31 75.36-11.88 101.03-37.53 33.58-33.55 32.57-75.6 21.5-101.42-7.94-18.51-23.08-33.55-43.79-43.48zm-76.32 71.76c-18.48 1.04-37.69-7.26-38.64-25.03-.7-13.18 9.38-27.89 39.78-29.64 3.48-.2 6.9-.3 10.25-.3 11.04 0 21.37 1.07 30.76 3.13-3.5 43.74-24.04 50.84-42.15 51.84z">
  </path>
</svg>
```

[image]

### Update

**@herrstrietzel** comments:

> You may add additional properties for passing appropriate viewBox
> values. A fixed viewBox and width height attributes will over
> complicate icon swapping.

- The icon's viewBox parameters should be equal to the physical size of
  the icon drawn in the vector editor, plus a minimum amount of padding
  so that the edges of the icon are not clipped to the edges of the SVG
  canvas. Since the width of the stroke is divided in half from the
  center line.

Instead of adjusting the size of the viewBox in a vector editor, you can use the universal method for calculating the size of the viewBox:

```
<script>
let  bb = threads.getBBox();
console.log(bb);
</script>
```

```html
<svg class="h-5 w-5 "  viewBox="0 0 128 128" width="128" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="border:1px solid red;">
<path fill="black" d="M105 0h302c57.75 0 105 47.25 105 105v302c0 57.75-47.25 105-105 105H105C47.25 512 0 464.75 0 407V105C0 47.25 47.25 0 105 0z"></path>
<path id="threads" fill="white"   d="M337.36 243.58c-1.46-.7-2.95-1.38-4.46-2.02-2.62-48.36-29.04-76.05-73.41-76.33-25.6-.17-48.52 10.27-62.8 31.94l24.4 16.74c10.15-15.4 26.08-18.68 37.81-18.68h.4c14.61.09 25.64 4.34 32.77 12.62 5.19 6.04 8.67 14.37 10.39 24.89-12.96-2.2-26.96-2.88-41.94-2.02-42.18 2.43-69.3 27.03-67.48 61.21.92 17.35 9.56 32.26 24.32 42.01 12.48 8.24 28.56 12.27 45.26 11.35 22.07-1.2 39.37-9.62 51.45-25.01 9.17-11.69 14.97-26.84 17.53-45.92 10.51 6.34 18.3 14.69 22.61 24.73 7.31 17.06 7.74 45.1-15.14 67.96-20.04 20.03-44.14 28.69-80.55 28.96-40.4-.3-70.95-13.26-90.81-38.51-18.6-23.64-28.21-57.79-28.57-101.5.36-43.71 9.97-77.86 28.57-101.5 19.86-25.25 50.41-38.21 90.81-38.51 40.68.3 71.76 13.32 92.39 38.69 10.11 12.44 17.73 28.09 22.76 46.33l28.59-7.63c-6.09-22.45-15.67-41.8-28.72-57.85-26.44-32.53-65.1-49.19-114.92-49.54h-.2c-49.72.35-87.96 17.08-113.64 49.73-22.86 29.05-34.65 69.48-35.04 120.16v.24c.39 50.68 12.18 91.11 35.04 120.16 25.68 32.65 63.92 49.39 113.64 49.73h.2c44.2-.31 75.36-11.88 101.03-37.53 33.58-33.55 32.57-75.6 21.5-101.42-7.94-18.51-23.08-33.55-43.79-43.48zm-76.32 71.76c-18.48 1.04-37.69-7.26-38.64-25.03-.7-13.18 9.38-27.89 39.78-29.64 3.48-.2 6.9-.3 10.25-.3 11.04 0 21.37 1.07 30.76 3.13-3.5 43.74-24.04 50.84-42.15 51.84z">
</path>

</svg>

<script>
let  bb = threads.getBBox();
console.log(bb);

</script>
```

*Red square is border svg canvas*

- We substitute the received values from the JS console into
  the  new **viewBox="109.74 86 292.51 340"**

<svg class="h-5 w-5 "  viewBox="109.74 86 292.51 340" width="128" heig

```html
<svg class="h-5 w-5 "  viewBox="109.74 86 292.51 340" width="128" height="128" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="border:1px solid red;">
<path fill="black" d="M105 0h302c57.75 0 105 47.25 105 105v302c0 57.75-47.25 105-105 105H105C47.25 512 0 464.75 0 407V105C0 47.25 47.25 0 105 0z"></path>
<path id="threads" fill="white"  d="M337.36 243.58c-1.46-.7-2.95-1.38-4.46-2.02-2.62-48.36-29.04-76.05-73.41-76.33-25.6-.17-48.52 10.27-62.8 31.94l24.4 16.74c10.15-15.4 26.08-18.68 37.81-18.68h.4c14.61.09 25.64 4.34 32.77 12.62 5.19 6.04 8.67 14.37 10.39 24.89-12.96-2.2-26.96-2.88-41.94-2.02-42.18 2.43-69.3 27.03-67.48 61.21.92 17.35 9.56 32.26 24.32 42.01 12.48 8.24 28.56 12.27 45.26 11.35 22.07-1.2 39.37-9.62 51.45-25.01 9.17-11.69 14.97-26.84 17.53-45.92 10.51 6.34 18.3 14.69 22.61 24.73 7.31 17.06 7.74 45.1-15.14 67.96-20.04 20.03-44.14 28.69-80.55 28.96-40.4-.3-70.95-13.26-90.81-38.51-18.6-23.64-28.21-57.79-28.57-101.5.36-43.71 9.97-77.86 28.57-101.5 19.86-25.25 50.41-38.21 90.81-38.51 40.68.3 71.76 13.32 92.39 38.69 10.11 12.44 17.73 28.09 22.76 46.33l28.59-7.63c-6.09-22.45-15.67-41.8-28.72-57.85-26.44-32.53-65.1-49.19-114.92-49.54h-.2c-49.72.35-87.96 17.08-113.64 49.73-22.86 29.05-34.65 69.48-35.04 120.16v.24c.39 50.68 12.18 91.11 35.04 120.16 25.68 32.65 63.92 49.39 113.64 49.73h.2c44.2-.31 75.36-11.88 101.03-37.53 33.58-33.55 32.57-75.6 21.5-101.42-7.94-18.51-23.08-33.55-43.79-43.48zm-76.32 71.76c-18.48 1.04-37.69-7.26-38.64-25.03-.7-13.18 9.38-27.89 39.78-29.64 3.48-.2 6.9-.3 10.25-.3 11.04 0 21.37 1.07 30.76 3.13-3.5 43.74-24.04 50.84-42.15 51.84z">
</path>

</svg>
```

- To get a multi-color icon, use gradients, as in the answer below

```html
<svg class="h-5 w-5 "  viewBox="109.74 86 292.51 340" width="128" height="128" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" >
<defs>
 <linearGradient id="grad" gradientTransform="rotate(70 0.5 0.5)">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#6F41BE" />
      <stop offset="25%" stop-color="#AC3097" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#DD2D74" />
      <stop offset="75%" stop-color="#F27932" />
      <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#FAC864" />
    </linearGradient>
</defs>
<path fill="black" d="M105 0h302c57.75 0 105 47.25 105 105v302c0 57.75-47.25 105-105 105H105C47.25 512 0 464.75 0 407V105C0 47.25 47.25 0 105 0z"></path>
<path id="threads" fill="url(#grad)" fill-rule="nonzero" d="M337.36 243.58c-1.46-.7-2.95-1.38-4.46-2.02-2.62-48.36-29.04-76.05-73.41-76.33-25.6-.17-48.52 10.27-62.8 31.94l24.4 16.74c10.15-15.4 26.08-18.68 37.81-18.68h.4c14.61.09 25.64 4.34 32.77 12.62 5.19 6.04 8.67 14.37 10.39 24.89-12.96-2.2-26.96-2.88-41.94-2.02-42.18 2.43-69.3 27.03-67.48 61.21.92 17.35 9.56 32.26 24.32 42.01 12.48 8.24 28.56 12.27 45.26 11.35 22.07-1.2 39.37-9.62 51.45-25.01 9.17-11.69 14.97-26.84 17.53-45.92 10.51 6.34 18.3 14.69 22.61 24.73 7.31 17.06 7.74 45.1-15.14 67.96-20.04 20.03-44.14 28.69-80.55 28.96-40.4-.3-70.95-13.26-90.81-38.51-18.6-23.64-28.21-57.79-28.57-101.5.36-43.71 9.97-77.86 28.57-101.5 19.86-25.25 50.41-38.21 90.81-38.51 40.68.3 71.76 13.32 92.39 38.69 10.11 12.44 17.73 28.09 22.76 46.33l28.59-7.63c-6.09-22.45-15.67-41.8-28.72-57.85-26.44-32.53-65.1-49.19-114.92-49.54h-.2c-49.72.35-87.96 17.08-113.64 49.73-22.86 29.05-34.65 69.48-35.04 120.16v.24c.39 50.68 12.18 91.11 35.04 120.16 25.68 32.65 63.92 49.39 113.64 49.73h.2c44.2-.31 75.36-11.88 101.03-37.53 33.58-33.55 32.57-75.6 21.5-101.42-7.94-18.51-23.08-33.55-43.79-43.48zm-76.32 71.76c-18.48 1.04-37.69-7.26-38.64-25.03-.7-13.18 9.38-27.89 39.78-29.64 3.48-.2 6.9-.3 10.25-.3 11.04 0 21.37 1.07 30.76 3.13-3.5 43.74-24.04 50.84-42.15 51.84z">
</path>

</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Update: I was able to make it work using a [different](https://fontawesomeicons.com/svg/icons/instagram-threads) svg and adding
> transform:"scale=(0.66)"

This T[hreads SVG Icon utility](https://fontawesomeicons.com/svg/icons/instagram-threads) of your choice does not yet have the option to get multi-color gradients.

[image]

Therefore, you need to manually write the code for the gradients:

```
<defs>
 <linearGradient id="grad1" gradientTransform="rotate(70 0.5 0.5)">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#6F41BE" />
      <stop offset="25%" stop-color="#AC3097" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#DD2D74" />
      <stop offset="75%" stop-color="#F27932" />
      <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#FAC864" />
    </linearGradient>
</defs>
```

Color values can be taken using a dropper in any graphic editor from raster icon samples

[image]

- Below is the result:

```html
<svg class="h-5 w-5 align-baseline sm:h-6 sm:w-6"    viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="128" height="128" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="border:0px solid red;">
<defs>
 <linearGradient id="grad1" gradientTransform="rotate(70 0.5 0.5)">
      <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#6F41BE" />
      <stop offset="25%" stop-color="#AC3097" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#DD2D74" />
      <stop offset="75%" stop-color="#F27932" />
      <stop offset="90%" stop-color="#FAC864" />
    </linearGradient>
</defs>
    <!-- Black Background  the icon -->
 <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" rx="10" ry="10" /> 
     <!-- Instagram Threads SVG Logo -->
<path fill="url(#grad1)" fill-rule="nonzero" transform=" translate(-65 -60) scale(1.25)"
 d="M337.36 243.58c-1.46-.7-2.95-1.38-4.46-2.02-2.62-48.36-29.04-76.05-73.41-76.33-25.6-.17-48.52 10.27-62.8 31.94l24.4 16.74c10.15-15.4 26.08-18.68 37.81-18.68h.4c14.61.09 25.64 4.34 32.77 12.62 5.19 6.04 8.67 14.37 10.39 24.89-12.96-2.2-26.96-2.88-41.94-2.02-42.18 2.43-69.3 27.03-67.48 61.21.92 17.35 9.56 32.26 24.32 42.01 12.48 8.24 28.56 12.27 45.26 11.35 22.07-1.2 39.37-9.62 51.45-25.01 9.17-11.69 14.97-26.84 17.53-45.92 10.51 6.34 18.3 14.69 22.61 24.73 7.31 17.06 7.74 45.1-15.14 67.96-20.04 20.03-44.14 28.69-80.55 28.96-40.4-.3-70.95-13.26-90.81-38.51-18.6-23.64-28.21-57.79-28.57-101.5.36-43.71 9.97-77.86 28.57-101.5 19.86-25.25 50.41-38.21 90.81-38.51 40.68.3 71.76 13.32 92.39 38.69 10.11 12.44 17.73 28.09 22.76 46.33l28.59-7.63c-6.09-22.45-15.67-41.8-28.72-57.85-26.44-32.53-65.1-49.19-114.92-49.54h-.2c-49.72.35-87.96 17.08-113.64 49.73-22.86 29.05-34.65 69.48-35.04 120.16v.24c.39 50.68 12.18 91.11 35.04 120.16 25.68 32.65 63.92 49.39 113.64 49.73h.2c44.2-.31 75.36-11.88 101.03-37.53 33.58-33.55 32.57-75.6 21.5-101.42-7.94-18.51-23.08-33.55-43.79-43.48zm-76.32 71.76c-18.48 1.04-37.69-7.26-38.64-25.03-.7-13.18 9.38-27.89 39.78-29.64 3.48-.2 6.9-.3 10.25-.3 11.04 0 21.37 1.07 30.76 3.13-3.5 43.74-24.04 50.84-42.15 51.84z">
  </path>

</svg>
```

- Second sample icon:

[image]

```html
<svg class="h-5 w-5 align-baseline sm:h-6 sm:w-6"    viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="128" height="128" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" style="border:0px solid red;">
<defs>
 <linearGradient id="grad1" gradientTransform="rotate(-180 0.5 0.5)">
      <stop offset="5%"  stop-color="#992EBD" />
      <stop offset="25%" stop-color="#CA2B81" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#E64F50" />
      <stop offset="65%" stop-color="#F87924" />
      <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#F9D977" />
    </linearGradient>
</defs>
 <rect fill="url(#grad1)" width="100%" height="100%"  rx="10" ry="10" />
<path fill="white" fill-rule="nonzero" transform=" translate(-65 -60) scale(1.25)"
 d="M337.36 243.58c-1.46-.7-2.95-1.38-4.46-2.02-2.62-48.36-29.04-76.05-73.41-76.33-25.6-.17-48.52 10.27-62.8 31.94l24.4 16.74c10.15-15.4 26.08-18.68 37.81-18.68h.4c14.61.09 25.64 4.34 32.77 12.62 5.19 6.04 8.67 14.37 10.39 24.89-12.96-2.2-26.96-2.88-41.94-2.02-42.18 2.43-69.3 27.03-67.48 61.21.92 17.35 9.56 32.26 24.32 42.01 12.48 8.24 28.56 12.27 45.26 11.35 22.07-1.2 39.37-9.62 51.45-25.01 9.17-11.69 14.97-26.84 17.53-45.92 10.51 6.34 18.3 14.69 22.61 24.73 7.31 17.06 7.74 45.1-15.14 67.96-20.04 20.03-44.14 28.69-80.55 28.96-40.4-.3-70.95-13.26-90.81-38.51-18.6-23.64-28.21-57.79-28.57-101.5.36-43.71 9.97-77.86 28.57-101.5 19.86-25.25 50.41-38.21 90.81-38.51 40.68.3 71.76 13.32 92.39 38.69 10.11 12.44 17.73 28.09 22.76 46.33l28.59-7.63c-6.09-22.45-15.67-41.8-28.72-57.85-26.44-32.53-65.1-49.19-114.92-49.54h-.2c-49.72.35-87.96 17.08-113.64 49.73-22.86 29.05-34.65 69.48-35.04 120.16v.24c.39 50.68 12.18 91.11 35.04 120.16 25.68 32.65 63.92 49.39 113.64 49.73h.2c44.2-.31 75.36-11.88 101.03-37.53 33.58-33.55 32.57-75.6 21.5-101.42-7.94-18.51-23.08-33.55-43.79-43.48zm-76.32 71.76c-18.48 1.04-37.69-7.26-38.64-25.03-.7-13.18 9.38-27.89 39.78-29.64 3.48-.2 6.9-.3 10.25-.3 11.04 0 21.37 1.07 30.76 3.13-3.5 43.74-24.04 50.84-42.15 51.84z">
  </path>

</svg>
```

- Icon with multicolor gradients shapes and frames

[image]

```html
<svg class="h-5 w-5 align-baseline sm:h-6 sm:w-6"    viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="128" height="128" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"   xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" >
<defs>
 <linearGradient id="grad1" gradientTransform="rotate(-180 0.5 0.5)">
      <stop offset="5%"  stop-color="#992EBD" />
      <stop offset="25%" stop-color="#CA2B81" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#E64F50" />
      <stop offset="65%" stop-color="#F87924" />
      <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#F9D977" />
    </linearGradient>> 
       <linearGradient id="grad2" gradientTransform="rotate(70 0.5 0.5)">
      <stop offset="15%"  stop-color="#992EBD" />
      <stop offset="35%" stop-color="#CA2B81" />
      <stop offset="50%" stop-color="#E64F50" />
      <stop offset="65%" stop-color="#F87924" />
      <stop offset="95%" stop-color="#F9D977" />
    </linearGradient>
</defs>
 <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" stroke-width="50" stroke="url(#grad1)"  />
<path fill="url(#grad2)" fill-rule="nonzero" transform=" translate(-25 -30) scale(1.1)"
 d="M337.36 243.58c-1.46-.7-2.95-1.38-4.46-2.02-2.62-48.36-29.04-76.05-73.41-76.33-25.6-.17-48.52 10.27-62.8 31.94l24.4 16.74c10.15-15.4 26.08-18.68 37.81-18.68h.4c14.61.09 25.64 4.34 32.77 12.62 5.19 6.04 8.67 14.37 10.39 24.89-12.96-2.2-26.96-2.88-41.94-2.02-42.18 2.43-69.3 27.03-67.48 61.21.92 17.35 9.56 32.26 24.32 42.01 12.48 8.24 28.56 12.27 45.26 11.35 22.07-1.2 39.37-9.62 51.45-25.01 9.17-11.69 14.97-26.84 17.53-45.92 10.51 6.34 18.3 14.69 22.61 24.73 7.31 17.06 7.74 45.1-15.14 67.96-20.04 20.03-44.14 28.69-80.55 28.96-40.4-.3-70.95-13.26-90.81-38.51-18.6-23.64-28.21-57.79-28.57-101.5.36-43.71 9.97-77.86 28.57-101.5 19.86-25.25 50.41-38.21 90.81-38.51 40.68.3 71.76 13.32 92.39 38.69 10.11 12.44 17.73 28.09 22.76 46.33l28.59-7.63c-6.09-22.45-15.67-41.8-28.72-57.85-26.44-32.53-65.1-49.19-114.92-49.54h-.2c-49.72.35-87.96 17.08-113.64 49.73-22.86 29.05-34.65 69.48-35.04 120.16v.24c.39 50.68 12.18 91.11 35.04 120.16 25.68 32.65 63.92 49.39 113.64 49.73h.2c44.2-.31 75.36-11.88 101.03-37.53 33.58-33.55 32.57-75.6 21.5-101.42-7.94-18.51-23.08-33.55-43.79-43.48zm-76.32 71.76c-18.48 1.04-37.69-7.26-38.64-25.03-.7-13.18 9.38-27.89 39.78-29.64 3.48-.2 6.9-.3 10.25-.3 11.04 0 21.37 1.07 30.76 3.13-3.5 43.74-24.04 50.84-42.15 51.84z">
  </path>

</svg>
```